# ASP.NET MVC 5 Single Sign On pattern without Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm trying to implement a single sign on pattern for my web application over several domains. I was about to use Forms Authentication but I came across this:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284380/is-formsauthentication-obsolete

If it's obsolete, what's the recommended alternate solution? I've domains like:

- account.domain.com (Users will login using this)
- app1.domain.com
- app2.domain.com
- app3.domain.com

Also, the main issue I'm facing with Forms Authentication is the user identity. I've a custom user object which has ALOT of properties. Storing and retrieving the object from session everytime is a pain. How can i overcome this difficulty?

Comment: I recommend https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3 to get a good start. It has got all the features which we need. It's just plug and play for single signon and token based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.Net Identity with Claims. *You do not need to use the entire ASP.Net Identity comes with ASP.Net Template.*

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YOUR_APP.Startup))]    
namespace YOUR_APP
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                CookieDomain = ".domain.com",
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more regathering how to attach claims at [A primer on OWIN cookie authentication middleware for the ASP.NET developer](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/).

***FYI***: make sure you set same machine key in all web.config files, so that cookies can be shared between sites.